# Multiple mouseenter / mouseleave events fired on overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So i have a simple setup of a #container div, that contains a #field div. 
I also have an invisible #hover span that follows mouse movement (centered) and gets visible while hovering over #field.

HTML:

```
<body>
        <div id="container" >
            <div id="field"></div>
        </div>
        <span id="mouseHover" ></span>
</body>
```

JS:

```
 $("#field").on({
    mousemove: function (e) {
        var left = parseInt($("#container").css("left")) || 0;
        var top = parseInt($("#container").css("top")) || 0;
        var newX = e.pageX - left - parseInt($("#mouseHover").css("width")) / 2;
        var newY = e.pageY - top - parseInt($("#mouseHover").css("height")) / 2;
        $("#mouseHover").css({ left: newX, top: newY });
       console.log("MMove");
    },
    mouseenter: function(e){
        $("#mouseHover").show();
        console.log("MEnter");
    },
    mouseleave: function(e){
        $("#mouseHover").hide();;
        console.log("MLeave");
    }
});
```

When hovering over the field though, it fires countless mouseenter and mouseleave (+ intended mousemove) events as soon as i move the mouse. This seems to be the case because the #hover span is centered around the mouse and everytime i move the mouse I technically leave #field and enter #hover, and then leave #hover and enter #field again and again, resulting in the #hover to show and hide continuously.

One solution i have is to not center the #hover around the mouse, so the mouse does not touch the bounds of the span and thus doesn't leave #field. But i want it centered ^^

The other is to give the span a negative z-index, which is no real solution because the #hover disappears behind the #field as soon as it gets a bgcolor.

[JSFiddle with the problem (#hover is "flashing" when centered around mouse)](https://jsfiddle.net/6rauo9ba/)

What would be the correct approach here :) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try giving the `#mouseHover` element a [`pointer-events` CSS property](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events) value of 'none'. Here is an [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6rauo9ba/1/).

```
#mouseHover { 
    // ...
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Comment: (plus 1) really a good answer. I just learnt a new technique from you. good job.

Comment: this is actually what i searched for, a way to disable all mouse events on an element. Why did i not find that ^^ Thanks a lot!!! This does not seem to be a very common way (seeing rajaprabhu above), how would this be handled else, or does no one do this ?

Comment: As long as you don't need to support <IE10 and also don't want mouse interactions within `#mouseHover`, there is no reason you shouldn't use this method.

Comment: Check @CBroe's answer for how to do it. Basically you need to implement that feature in your style. If you are concerned about the browser support (why, most browsers in use today actually do support it), you may consider wrapping your handlers inside this: `if(e.target === this[0]){ /* rest of your handler code here */ }`

Answer (score 0):

> One solution i have is to not center the #hover around the mouse, so the mouse does not touch the bounds of the span and thus doesn't leave #field.

That one you could easily achieve in modern browsers, by using `pointer-events` to make it “untouchable” by the mouse cursor:

```
#mouseHover {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6rauo9ba/3/

That of course will only be a solution, if you don’t need to interact with the content inside the `#mouseHover` element in any way.

And you might want to check browser support, to see what older browsers you might need a fallback solution for. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events